# How to get latitude and longitude?

Tags: geolocation

As we know it is possible to get latitude and longitude of every popular place on google maps.But what if I want to find out latitude and longitude of every place where I am standing without help of google maps?Is there any specific device which will help me to do this?

Comment: Your question is off topic here, but the answer is *a sextant and a chronometer*.

Comment: I am searching for a digital device which can give me the dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a Global Positioning System which is also commonly known as GPS. Some good brand name devices are Garmin and TomTom.

If you would like to accomplish finding your location through an Android phone or iOS device using strategies involving GSM, Wi-Fi, Cell towers, etc. Here are some links:

Android Location Strategies: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html
iOS Core Location: http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/ios-corelocation-tutorial/

Comment: Will It possible to use android's gps to find location without use of google-maps,I meant android-gps directly connecting to the sattelite and getting lattitudes and longitudes?

Comment: Yes, you can retrieve location through a GPS Location Provider or Network Location Provider!